# how to open whatsapp with out scanning QR code

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, browser, front-camera, qr-code

i want to open *whats app* in browser . but i have to scan the `QR code` produced in the browser through camera.

is there any way to get my whats in browser.

problem is my *camera* is not working it is not even opening .so i cant scan it .
is there any way to open it?

which tells how QR code works.

**how do i permit whats app in browser?**

Comment: It looks like you already found that your question was asked before.

Comment: @Dan Hulme I HAVE ASKED FOR AN  ALETERNATIVE WAY

Comment: You need to read site rules and know how it works here. Asking a duplicate question, even if the dupe target hasn't got a satisfactory (in your eyes) answer, isn't allowed.